# Odoo Comunity Error: Este código de barras no se puede analizar parcial o completamente

Tags: windows10, odoo

e instalado Odoo community en mi ordenador y al usar el lector de codigo de barras por usb me sale el error `Error: Este código de barras no se puede analizar parcial o completamente.`

Si situó el cursos sobre el buscador y uso el lector de código de barras, escribe correctamente el código y encuentra el producto, pero al usarlo directamente para agregar productos da el siguiente error, adjunto las imágenes.

Alguno sabrá como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola TaTu picatatu, bienvenido,  la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, 
aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Hola. Esto parece más un problema de la versión de post que estás usando. Que navegador utilizas? Posiblemente se minimice si utilizas algúno de los navegadores basados en chromiun como "Edge", "Chrome",  "Opera".